# How can I make VSCode recognize Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

I have tried installing Selenium several different ways, navigating to several different folders with the Command Prompt. But every time I install it, I get the following:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\(me)\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\(me)\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.10)
```

When I try a basic test in VSCode, I get this:

```
<ipython-input-1-8510f5dbbe17> in <module>
----> 1 from selenium import webdriver
      2 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      3 driver.get('https://www.nasa.gov')
      4 headlines = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("headline")
      5 for headline in headlines:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I also tried installing Selenium.Webdriver using NuGet, but I got this error:

```
Cannot find any .csproj or .fsproj for your project! Please fix this error.
```

I'm surely overlooking something basic. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you use "`pip`" to install the module "`selenium`" in the current [python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments):

1. Check whether the installation tool "`pip`" comes from the currently selected environment:

   [image]
2. Use the command "`pip install selenium`" or "`pip3 install selenium`" to install the module.
3. Check whether the installation is successful: "`pip list`" or "`pip3 list`"

   [image]
4. Run:

   [image]

More reference: [Use Python in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites).

Comment: Thanks -- that got me most of the way there. Making sure Chromedrive was on my path was the last step.